# How to Save Identify Results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, identify, results

In Arcmap and specifically using a WMS layer that I cannot access the attribute table of, how can I 'intercept' or extract the results from using the Identify tool from the toolbar? I would like to piggyback on the identify tool and use the results for my own means. This would be very handy for a WMS layer that I can't quickly get to the attribute table of. I could identify certain features and then route the feature information into a table for my own use.

With leaflet, I can do something similar by constructing a query against the WMS and using the returned json as feature data.

[image]

I hope that I am overlooking something or some tool so basic that already exists for this situation. If so, please let me know.

Added images after Alex' comment to show that the 'Select' option is greyed out. Also the Data > Export is not available for this WMS layer.

[image]

Comment: Copy Record is not greyed out. You can then paste into text editor / spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to select the features you've identified is to right-click the layer name in the left panel of the Identify window and choose Select. The features that were identified will be selected.

Now you can right-click the layer in the TOC and choose Data > Export data or do anything else you wish.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more adamant that this is for when I can't access the attribute tables. These options are greyed out for the WMS layer that I am using.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a corresponding image like yours. The simple logic in my head is that this data is being sent to ArcMAP in some format, thus I should be able to get it in a different view than the identify box gives me.

Comment: @Barrett, you won't be able to download the source data from ArcMap while connecting to the WMS service. Even if you see that the features are in ArcMap, you are not entitled to obtaining the source geometry and attributes data. You should probably contact the service author and see if they can share the data with you. Alternatively, you might ask for the web interface to the service, so you could potentially download data yourself if applicable.

Comment: The service allows querys through the REST interface which gives me the same data. I do not see the problem downloading the attribute data from the identify button. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: No "download source data" button in the Identify window, you cannot download the source data in ArcMap. You need to access the service interface in a way that allows downloading the data (if allowed by author), check the use constraints.